# Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript doesn't load popup

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my project there is a print button . after clicking that button I want to open a popup but it's not loading

```
   <table class="inputForm">
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
         <td align="right">
          <asp:Button ID="btnPrint" OnClick="btnPrint_Click" Text="Printuiuiuiui" CssClass="button" runat="server" Visible="true" />
         </td>
      </tr>
     </tfoot>
    </table>
```

```cs
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "s1", "<script FOR=window EVENT=onload>openViewer('" + (int)ABCDEF.enReportName.PortfolioPrint + "');</script>");
```

openViewer is a function that shows popup

```js
function openViewer(reportName) {

  sPath = "/ADDCD/Popups/ifggfjfj.aspx?Viewer.aspx?ReportName=" + reportName;
   
  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1) {

    return window.open(sPath, self, "dialogHeight: 374px; dialogWidth: 430px; status: no; resizable: no; center: yes;");
  }
  else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1) {

    return window.open(sPath, self, "dialogHeight: 374px; dialogWidth: 430px; status: no; resizable: no; center: yes;");
  }
  else if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) || (!!document.documentMode == true)) { //IF IE > 10
           
    return window.showModalDialog(sPath, self, "dialogHeight: 374px; dialogWidth: 430px; status: no; resizable: no; center: yes;");

  }
}
```

I tried with Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScriptBlock but not working . Anybody have any idea why it's not working?

Comment: Have your tried with Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock instead of Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: if you don't use the <asp:button with server-side code, simply you can use the input type button, and then put our code.
but if you are using server-side before showing the popup page, then you can pass a parameter to query string to indicate the javascript to open a popup once the response return from the server

Comment: @M.Ruiz I tried ut not working at all

Comment: @AhmadHindash I don't want to change asp utton to input type

Comment: I tried it and your code and it worked as expected. Make sure your openViewer function is defined before the call, e.g. try to move the openViewer function to a script in the head of the page.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while but try this. Move all the script tags and JS to the page. I think just call the function with the arguments it needs.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "openViewer", 
    "openViewer(" + (int)ABCDEF.enReportName.PortfolioPrint + ");", true);
```